# getFragmentByTag() never returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've five fragments in my activity. On the click of fragment drawer list, I'm calling `setFrament()` method.
It removes the previous fragments from the activity, and adds the new one as per the requirement.
Here's my code for `setFragment` method.

```
protected void setFragment(final int position) {
    // Remove currently active fragment
    if (mActiveFragment != null) {
        Fragment previous;
        while ((previous = mFragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(mActiveFragment.toString())) != null) {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(previous).commit();
            Log.e("in loop", "stuck");
        }
    }

    // It's enum, generated according to position
    FragmentType type = getFragmentType(position);

    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(type.toString());
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment(type);

    }

    mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.containerFrameLayout, fragment,
                    type.toString()).commit();
    // Sets the current selected fragment checked in
    // Drawer listview
    mFragmentDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    // set Actionbar title

    getActionBar().setTitle(type + "");
    mActiveFragment = type;

}
```

Here, while changing the fragment, it keeps prining "stuck" in while loop forever,
 my question is,
why `remove(Fragment)` method doesn't remove the previous fragment from the activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commit()` is an asynchronous call that is only executed when the Android system regains control.  The fragments won't be removed until some time after you leave the method.

If you want to remove the previous fragment (assuming there's only one), then you can add them to the backstack.  Then you can call `popBackStack(null, 0)` which will pop everything on the back stack.  The side catch though is pressing the "back" button will also pop the backstack if the user were to do that.  You'll have to override the `onBackPressed()` and handle it yourself if you don't want that to happen.

EDIT:

One method would be to keep track of all IDs or TAGs and call `remove` on them individually.

```
LinkedList<Integer> fragmentIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

/*** Add fragment to FragmentManager ***/
fragmentIds.add(/** ID of fragment */);

/** Removing all fragments from FragmentManager **/
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragToRemove;
for(Integer id : fragmentIds)
{
   fragToRemove = fm.findFragmentById(id);
   transaction.remove(fragToRemove);
}
transaction.commit()
fragmentIds.clear();
```

However, you don't have to call `remove` on any of them so long as you use `replace()` method on the same container.  `replace()` will pop the previous fragment and add in the new one.  So long as the transaction isn't pushed to the backstack, the previous fragment is detached from the Activity and discarded.

Comment: well, currently there's only one fragment, but there can be many, that is the reason I'm using while loop. and I can't use popBackStack method as it doesn't suite my need. Any alternative ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the FragmentManager doesn't handle Fragments NOT on the backstack very well.  The only way I can think of is hold references to your Fragments and call `remove()` on each of them individually.  I'll update with a couple solutions, though I really don't like any of them.